# How can I get the height and width from an <img> tag with plain javascript?

Tags: javascript

I am looking to get the height and width defined within the  tag, not the original or actual height displayed on the page.

For example

```
<img id="testImg" src="http://test.com/img.png" height="300" width="250">
```

I would expect to return a height of 300 and width of 250.

In the example where the height and width are not defined within the tag:

```
<img id="testImg" src="http://test.com/img.png">
```

I would expect to return false or undefined or 0 for both the height and width.

With the JavaScript:

```
var img = document.getElementById("testImg");
console.log(img.naturalHeight);
console.log(img.height);
```

img.naturalHeight and img.height do not return what is defined within the tag. These return the original or actual image height.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider using [`getAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getAttribute) to retrieve attribute values from an element:

```js
var img = document.getElementById('testImg');
console.log(img.getAttribute('height'));
console.log(img.getAttribute('width'));

var img0 = document.getElementById('testImg0');
console.log(img0.getAttribute('height'));
console.log(img0.getAttribute('width'));
```

```html
<img id="testImg" src="http://test.com/img.png" height="300" width="250">
<img id="testImg0" src="http://test.com/img.png">
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the height and width of an `<img>` tag using plain JavaScript, you can use the `height` and `width` properties of the `HTMLImageElement` object. Here's an example:

```
<script>
    var imgElement = document.getElementById('myImage');

    // Get the height and width
    var height = imgElement.height;
    var width = imgElement.width;

    // Log the values
    console.log('Height:', height);
    console.log('Width:', width);
</script>
```